# Struggling with Plural/Singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following is a grammatically correct statement?

1. The value of cars depreciate over time.
2. The values of cars depreciate over time.
3. The value of cars depreciates over time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is incorrect.

> The **value** of cars **depreciate** over time.

The verb should agree with 'value', not cars.

For this reason, the 2nd and 3rd ones are both correct. Their usage depends on context.

Consider:

> The values of (most) cars depreciate over time.

***Values*** of different cars

and

> The value of (my) cars depreciates over time.

***Value*** of all my cars taken collectively

Comment: In which context would you use my second sentence and in which context would you use my third?

Comment: @stygian: See examples

Comment: Could you not use the third to describe ‘most cars’ collectively?

Comment: @stygian: Generally, no, but if your talking about the sum of their separate values (which is unlikely), then yes

Comment: I see. So if I were to refer to ‘most cars,’ even without using the word ‘most,’ I would use ‘values’ instead of ‘value.’ Yes?

Comment: @stygian: it boils down to this: you have to decide if the value is singular or plural in your context and use the verb accordingly.

Comment: @stygian: Correct.

Comment: @stygian You could get around the problem by saying *The value of any car depreciates over time*.